# Regexp in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I've got a simple .htaccess requirement that I'm failing on and would appreciate a pointer.

Content from an old CMS is being migrated to WordPress.  The old CMS posts are formatted in the following way:

```
{postid}-example-post-title
```

eg

```
101-this-is-an-old-post
```

I have a mapping table that links the old post ids to the new WordPress post ids, so in theory `\{oldid-*}` should map nicely to the WordPress standard `\?p={newid}` format.  I expected the following to work to redirect old url 101-this-is-the-post to the WordPress post 1660:

```
Redirect 301 /101-.*$ /?p=1660
```

The regexp /101-.*$ matches correctly, but for some reason my .htaccess file doesn't seem to recognise the regular expression.  Here's my full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine Off
SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 56
DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /101-(.*) /?p=1660
```

I've tried moving the Redirect to the top of the file, the bottom of the file and between the IfModule block to no avail.  I'm clearly missing something - any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Redirect doesn't expect a regexp (see doc). Use RedirectMatch instead or URL rewriting (RewriteRule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per julp's comment above, the solution to this problem was to use RewriteRule.  The following worked correctly, placed withing the IfModule block :

```
RewriteRule 301 /101-(.*) /?p=166
```